# searching a sentence in group of sentence in a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using datatable & searching a sentence from a group of sentences in a table. e.g. if I'm searching bachelor of accounting, I'm getting the result of both bachelor & accounting individually which I don't want.

```
<table>
<tr><td>University name</td>     <td>University course</td>
<td>ABC</td>                 <td>Bachelor of Accounting, Bachelor of Business </td>
<td>XYZ </td>                <td>Diploma of Management, Accounting  </td>   
<td>DEF </td>                <td>Master of business.</td>
</tr></table>
```

I am having a search button & I want a search button to match for the word I type. If I type bachelor of acc  I should get 1 result only but I'm getting 2.

```
var oTable =  $('#partnerTable').DataTable({
 .......
 .......
})

$('#partnerSearch').keyup(function(){
    oTable.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
});
```

Comment: what happens if you put your search string in quotes during the search process?

Comment: @JayJordan Is there any other way like we can use regex expression??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JSON.stringify to filter your search according to the data.

```
$('#partnerSearch').keyup(function(){
var search = JSON.stringify($(this).val())
oTable.search(search).draw() ;
});
```